DisplayIndex for DataGridViewColumn not working
I am adding DataGridViewColumns programmatically and would like to order the sequence in which the columns are displayed.
This is my code, but for some reason, the order is ignored when the DataGridView is displayed.
Columns.AddRange([
    new TextBoxColumn_ID() { DisplayIndex = 0 },
    new ComboBoxColumn_APPLICATION_NAME() { DisplayIndex = 1 },
    new TextBoxColumn_NAME() { DisplayIndex = 2 },
    new TextBoxColumn_DESCRIPTION() { DisplayIndex = 3 },
    new ComboBoxColumn_IDENTIFIABLE_BY_1() { DisplayIndex = 4 },
    new TextBoxColumn_IDENTIFIABLE_BY_1_VALUE() { DisplayIndex = 5 },
    new ComboBoxColumn_IDENTIFIABLE_BY_2() { DisplayIndex = 6 },
    new TextBoxColumn_IDENTIFIABLE_BY_2_VALUE() { DisplayIndex = 7 }
]);

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Does this answer your question? DataGridView column order does not seem to work
